# C# - Generic interfaces

Tags: c#

Where do generic interfaces are quite useful ? ( I am a beginner,so simple example will definitely helpful).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its useful when you need an interface, but you also need to abstract the data type. Simple example

```
public interface IMyShape<T>
{
   T X { get; }
   T Y { get; }
}

public class IntSquare : IMyShape<int>
{
   int X { get { return 100; } }
   int Y { get { return 100; } }
}

public class IntTriangle : IMyShape<int>
{
   int X { get { return 200; } }
   int Y { get { return 200; } }
}

public class FloatSquare : IMyShape<float>
{
   float X { get { return 100.05; } }
   float Y { get { return 100.05; } }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can look at [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Generic interfaces are really useful when you want to parameterize the types of one of the members in the interface.  Consider the `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` interfaces.  The first iterates `Objects` whereas the second iterates instances of the type argument supplied for `T`.

Since interfaces can be generic it allows you to leverage their flexibility while still taking advantage of generics in the same way that you would for a concrete type.